# AttributeError: FUN instance has no attribute '__trunc__'

Tags: python, numpy

here is my class FUN, but the result is showing `AttributeError: FUN instance has no attribute '__trunc__'`. please tell me where is the error in coding and what to modify.

```
import math
import random
import string
import numpy as np
import pickle
from itertools import chain

random.seed(0)

class FUN:
 def __init__(self):
    print "fun"
 # set a random numbers between a & b
 def rand(a, b):
    self.rand = (b-a)*random.random() + a
    return self.rand

 # sigmoid function, tanh ~ 1/(1+e^-x)
 def sigmoid(x):
     self.sig = math.tanh(x)
     return self.sig

 def sigmoid1(x):
    self.sig1 = 1/(1+math.exp(-x))
    return self.sig1

 # derivative of sigmoid function, in terms of the output (y)
 def dsigmoid(y):
    self.dsig = 1.0 - y**2
    return self.dsig
 # getting 2d array
 #def matrix(I, J, fill=0.0):
    #return [[val for col in range(I)] for row in range(J)]
 #obtain a matrix
 def matrix(I, J, fill=0.0):
    m = []
    for i in range(I):
        m.append([fill]*J)
    return m
f = FUN()
print f.matrix(2,3)
```

the above code is giving the following type of errors:

```
fun
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "functions.py", line 42, in <module>
 print f.matrix(2,3)
File "functions.py", line 38, in matrix
 for i in range(I):
AttributeError: FUN instance has no attribute '__trunc__'
```

please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Methods take a `self` argument as the first parameter; you named it `I` instead and passed that to `range()`, which then tries to turn the instance of your `FUN` custom class into a integer number<sup>†</sup>. That failed:

```
>>> class FUN: pass
... 
>>> range(FUN())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: FUN instance has no attribute '__trunc__'
```

*Add* a `self` argument:

```
def matrix(self, I, J, fill=0.0):
```

You'll need to do this for the other methods as well; all but the `__init__` method are missing `self`.

<sub><sup>†</sup> Python tries [`object.__int__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__int__) first, then tries `object.__trunc__`, a method surprisingly underdocumented. Only the [`math.truncate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.trunc) documentation and the [Numbers Type Hierarchy PEP 3141 proposal](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3141/) mention the method.</sub>

Comment: thanks for suggestion, it is working after putting self argument. But for the function random for float it is giving error as:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functions.py", line 43, in <module>
    print f.rand(2.0,3.1)
  File "functions.py", line 18, in rand
    self.rand = float((b-a)*random.random() + a)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'type' and 'type'

Comment: @Latik: You changed more than just adding `self` to the method signature then, because `def rand(self, a, b):`, then `self.rand = (b-a)*random.random() + a`, then `return self.rand` works fine.